# MySQL 5.7 STR_TO_DATE

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am running MySQL 5.7 and wanted to convert some strings to date. I referred the manual here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

And tried out the following(please note the MySQL version)

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('9','%m');
+-----------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('9','%m') |
+-----------------------+
| NULL                  |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '9' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But from the online manual for MySQL 5.7, I should see the following:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('9','%m');
        -> '0000-09-00'
```

Is there something that I'm missing, or could this be a bug?

Comment: From [Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html) (emphasis added): "*The default SQL mode in MySQL 5.7 includes these modes: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, **[`NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date)**, `NO_ZERO_DATE`, `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO`, `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER`, and `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says in the manual,

> If the NO_ZERO_DATE or NO_ZERO_IN_DATE SQL mode is enabled, zero dates or part of dates are disallowed. In that case, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and generates a warning

That causes the result to be NULL in cases such like this, because your partial “date” contains zero values.