# how to convert '202109' to 2021-09 in mysql

Tags: mysql

how to convert '202109' to 2021-09 in MySQL,

I tied

`select STR_TO_DATE('202109', '%Y-%m')`
and
`select DATE('202109', '%Y-%m')`

all failed,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL 5.7 STR\_TO\_DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223080/mysql-5-7-str-to-date)

Comment: You shouldn't (in strict mode - cannot) use datetime function on partial datetime value. Use string functions: `CONCAT(LEFT(value, 4), '-', RIGHT(value, 2))` or `CONCAT(value DIV 10000, '-', value MOD 100)`.

Comment: @slashroot This solved my problem `SELECT INSERT('202109', 5, 0, '-');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have string. So I think no need to deal with `date`.

```
SELECT INSERT('202109', 5, 0, '-');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change %Y-%m to %Y%m them just use DATE_FORMAT to get formart what you want

```
select DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE('202109', '%Y%m'), '%Y-%m') as ym_formart
```

Comment: it won't work on all servers, as indicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223080/mysql-5-7-str-to-date

Comment: @ProGu This answer solved my problem `SELECT INSERT('202109', 5, 0, '-');`